# Django cookiecutter with postgresql setup on Ubuntu 20.4 can't migrate

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I installed django cookiecutter in Ubuntu 20.4
with postgresql when I try to make migrate to the database I get this error:

> python manage.py migrate
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 381, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 375, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 323, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 361, in execute
> self.check()   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 387, in check
> all_issues = self._run_checks(   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
> line 64, in _run_checks
> issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
> line 72, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py",
> line 9, in check_database_backends
> for conn in connections.all():   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 216, in all
> return [self[alias] for alias in self]   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 213, in **iter**
> return iter(self.databases)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
> line 80, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 147, in databases
> self._databases = settings.DATABASES   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
> line 79, in **getattr**
> self._setup(name)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
> line 66, in _setup
> self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/home/mais/PycharmProjects/django_cookiecutter_task/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
> line 176, in **init**
> raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.") django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY
> setting must not be empty.

I did the whole instructions in cookiecutter docs and createdb what is the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Python libraries are so many and to make things simple and to enable the code to be re-usable, modules call each other. First of all, don't be scared on seeing such a big error. It is only a traceback to the error, as one code calls the other, which calls the other. To debug any such problem, it's important to see the first and last .py file names. In your case, the nesting in the traceback is like this:

[Traceback Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8W5G.jpg)

So, the key problem for you is **The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.**
I would recommend putting the secret key under the "config/.env" file, as mentioned here:

https://wemake-django-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/template/django.html#secret-settings-in-production

Initially, you should find the SECRET_KEY inside the setting.py file of the project folder. But it needs to be inside .env file in production/LIVE environment. And NEVER post the SECRET_KEY of live environments on github or even here, as it's a security risk.

Comment: the error was ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name.settings.dev' but I added an empty file dev.py to the settings directory and then got this error

Comment: Is it related to the link that you get cookiecutter from?

Comment: Only add files if it is mentioned. Also, if you are trying new software, try it in a docker container. That way you do not spoil your system's libraries. Now, you have 3 options: 1. Post all the new error logs 2. Start fresh on a docker container 3. Follow each of the steps here: https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html And please do not rush, it leads to mistakes and you get de-motivated thinking that you cannot learn Django. I think you can learn Django, just go a bit slower :)

Comment: Also, if you can share what project you are trying to implement, so we can troubleshoot it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is very clear in the logs.

You need to set your environment `SECRET_KEY` give it a value, and it should skip this error message, it might throw another error if there are some other configurations that are not set properly.